# Using condition sum function in a Filemaker portal

Tags: sum, conditional-statements, filemaker, portal, records

Hi I would like to sum only some records of my Filemaker portal.

I have only two fields:

1) size, 2) comments

I would like to make three different sums with the portal records:
a) sum rows with size below 7 cm
b) sum rows with size between 8-14 cm
c) sum rows with size above 15 cm

I know how to use the conditional in a normal fiel, but I've been looking how to apply the conditional in a portal and I haven't found any solution.

Comment: The problem with your question is this: there are about 5 or 6 different ways this could be handled, each with their own pros and cons. Why don't you give us some background, like: what is your data about, how much of it is there and - most importantly - why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create three new calculation fields in your portal table, one for each size range you want to sum. The calculation would be empty if the size it outside its range, or would contain the value you want to sum if it matches. Then sum up these calculations instead.

If you want to avoid adding fields, you could use ExecuteSQL to get the sums dynamically when the layout loads, or when the size range criteria change.